# Unity Pattern For Moving Some Objects Between Scenes?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a pattern to transition between scenes, moving one instance of an object to the next scene and then later returning it to the prior scene, but without destroying the other objects that were in the prior scene. Here is the context:

- When my game loads, it connects to my server to get the list of characters the player can control and instantiates them dynamically from a prefab.
- The loading script moves each character game object to the main scene and then loads that scene.
- The main scene now has the characters, which can be interacted with. So far, so good. One of the commands is to pick a specific character and send them on a task, which has its own task scene.
- I can move that character to the task scene and move them back when the task is completed. However, the other characters who were not on the task and should not be in the task scene are now destroyed because the main scene was unloaded.

I'm looking for a pattern to accomplish this. Most of what I've read suggests using DontDestroyOnLoad, but this actually moves all characters into all scenes, which results in too many characters in the task scene. Another option might be to create a game object that holds all the character information, pass that between scenes and have logic in each scene to re-instantiate the appropriate character[s] in that scene. This feels like a lot of overhead since I have no other reason to be wiping and recreating them constantly. Perhaps a third option is to restructure my game so the task scene is just added to the main scene and shows up as some kind of overlay that blocks/captures input. This sounds messy and likely to have performance issues (targeting Android).

Does anyone have a good pattern for this?

Comment: Do you need more than one instance of each character?  Static declaration would do it, as long as you don't need 2 "archers" or whatever.

Comment: Yes, I need multiple characters, which is why I have this issue--moving one character around is comparatively simple. Each character is an explorer. You, the player, can hire them (resulting in more than one) and you can send them on adventures. Only one explorer can go on each adventure, and the other explorers need to remain in the main scene while they aren't adventuring.

Comment: Static List<class> should work.  As you create them, add them to the list.

Comment: And yes, I got that there were multiple characters.  I assumed you had 1 class for each character type, but perhaps only 1 instance of each class (1 wizard, 1 archer, 1 thief, etc).

Comment: Ah, no, I have a class Explorer of which there could be n instances (probably up to a reasonable number such as 10--too many mouths to feed beyond that!).

Comment: Your suggestion is to create a static array/list of all the characters with state information needed for any given scene, then just switch scenes and instantiate as required, updating changes back to the static? Did I get that right? Seems a lot cleaner than trying to load scenes additive and deal with multiple cameras, audio listeners, event systems, etc.

Comment: Yes. You will be able to access them from any scene... Later on, perhaps you're questing with character 1 and character 2 needs to come help... NP, he's ready for you.  All characters get xp, even when not present?  Np...

Comment: Thanks! I'll create a singleton game manager to track the explorers and go from there. How do I credit you with answering my question successfully? Brand new to this.

Comment: I have to mark it as an answer, or you should be able to upvote these comments (not sure if there's a minimum score or not before it lets you vote on comments).  I'll make an answer for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Turning comments into an answer.

Static variables can be accessed from any scene.  Depending on the number of each class type you need, you can either instantiate a static class, or a static List/Array of class.  Once you add your objects to it, you can access them from anywhere.

As long as this doesn't become a memory concern (thousands of large objects, eg), this should work well for your purposes (a few characters that need to persist throughout the game anyway).

Comment: But static variable purpose is not that. Also, it will lead to loss of data. A collection of game object will not survive the reload. So no, this is not an appropriate answer.

Comment: I always research before posting, unless it's really silly. This was my reference before posting.  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/41891/static-variables-between-scenes.html

Comment: Well, despite the 20+ upvote, that does not make it right. I assume 19 of them were from beginners just happy to have a working solution. It does not make it right though. Static have a different purpose. PlayerPrefs and DontDestroyOnLoad have that purpose to save data over scene or over sessions.

Comment: I'm not saying you're info is incorrect.  I'm just "showing my work" to show how I came up with it.  Based on the answer, it seemed to be accepted and accurate.

Comment: FYI - I didn't take the answer 100% literally. I have a List of my explorers in my singleton GameManager (state machine, basically) and for every scene I instantiate the explorer prefab and refer to that explorer's stats in the GameManager. Working great so far. The List itself is not static, but it's part of the singleton.

Answer (score 1):

with the scene manager you can create an empty scene, in this empty scene you put all of the objects you want to keep.

After you unload your first scene (not the one you create) and you load the next scene.

When your next scene is load you transfer all the object from the scene you create to the scene you just load.

PS : you have multiple scene load at the same time check this link for more informations : 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html